# I have a kdump kernel core dump; how can I analyze it?

Tags: kernel, crash, core-dump, hang, kdump

After installing kdump-related packages and yet another hang, I now have a:

```
/var/crash/kexec_cmd
```

file. But what can I do with it? Should I use the command-line `crash` utility? I tried to, but it wanted my kernel file and didn't accept `/vmlinuz`. Is there other something else I can/should use?

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: No, I wasn't, and now my hardware and software has changed...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the GNU debugger, [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/). See this older [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115613/core-dump-file-analysis) for more info.

Comment: No, you're wrong: `"/var/crash/kexec_cmd" is not a core dump: File format not recognized`.